# How do I dynamically inline an SVG loaded via file-loader?

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js, vue-component

I was using `svg-inline-loader` to inline my SVGs which worked perfectly.

However, I also need to use those SVGs elsewhere not inline so I cannot using `svg-inline-loader`. I need to use `file-loader` to import my SVGs.

It seems like it would be easy to inline my SVGs, there are multiple components available that do just that. However, I also need to do it dynamically based on the name of the icon required.

This makes it awkward as I can't find a way to dynamically import a file and inline it on the page.

Using an **`import()`** doesn't work. Neither does **`require()`**.

```
<template>
    <span class="s-icon" v-bind:class="[typeAndSize, optionClasses]" v-html="icon"></span>
</template>

computed: {
    icon () {
        return () => import(`../../../../node_modules/my-lib/images/svg-icons/${this.name}.svg`);
    },
```

Has anyone tackled this issue before? Or can anyone point me in the right direction.

**Edit**

Further to my comment on the accepted answer this is the full solution I ended up with:

```
const icon = require(`!!svg-inline-loader!../../../../node_modules/my-lib/images/svg-icons/${this.name}.svg`);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use inline query string format, in order to apply only specific loader and ignore the rest.

```
const icon = require('!!file-loader!./icon.svg')
```

For dynamic imports you may look to [require-context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context)

Comment: This essentially works, though I used `svg-inline-loader` to get the SVG content. `file-loader` just gives me the webpack file name.

Comment: Wow. This issue has been messing with me for a long time. Thanks both for posting about it!